# Detect button click of a dynamic table contains dynamic buttons with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html-table

I have the following `table` dynamically generated using `php` and `MySQL`. The number of rows and number of buttons generated are dynamic.

```html
<?php
if($resultCheck != 0){
    while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($tableQueryExecute)){
      $normalShiftDuration = $result['shift1Duration'];
?>  
        <tr> <form method="post" id="vtagViewTwo">         
        <td name=""><select class="form-control" name="normalShiftOa" id="normalShiftOa"><option>1</option></select></td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="editButton" id="editButton" value="Save">
        </td>
        </form></tr> 
<?php
        }
                
    }
?>
```

I want to get value of the `<td>` which is `normalShiftOa` value with the button click using `jQuery` `click event` as below.

```js
$("#editButton").click(function(){
    alert("Clicked");
});
```

But since there are many button generating for each row with the same `id`, I am not able to do it. Does anyone know how to do it? I am able to do it using `php` `$_POST['editButton']` method. But I want to do it using jQuery.

**Edit 1**

I changed the id `editButton` to class and tried the following. But it is not working

```js
$(".editButton").click(function(){
    alert($(this).$("#normalShiftOa").val());
});
```

Comment: Well Id should be unique, so change `id="editButton"` to `class="editButton"` and then use `$(".editButton")` and inside the click function `$(this)` will refer to the button your clicked

Comment: you can generate id also dynamic because you are in loop like `id="normalShiftOa_<?php echo  $result['id']?>"`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Can you please show a simple example?

Comment: @AsifChaudhary But how to get that `$result['id']` to Jquery click event?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yes you are right. I just edited my code to show it here and there was this extra line came during the process. My actual code doesn't have that. Thanks for the reminder

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Can you please see my edit in the question. I tried the method you said, but not working too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using ids, use class `editButton`. Then, if you want to get the value of the `select`, use jQuery like shown below:

```
$(".editButton").click(function(){
  let tdValue = $(this).closest("form").find("select").val();
});
```

**Edit:** Code snippet that works.

```js
  
   $(".editButton").click(function(event){
      let tdValue = $(this).closest("form").find("select").val();
      alert(tdValue);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr> <form method="post" id="vtagViewTwo">         
        <td name=""><select class="form-control" name="normalShiftOa" id="normalShiftOa"><option>1</option></select></td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" class="editButton btn btn-primary" name="editButton" id="editButton" value="Save">
        </td>
        </form></tr>
```

Comment: So I did this way `let tdValue = $(this).closest("#vtagViewTwo").find("#normalShiftOa").val();` and then tried `alert(tdValue);`. But not working. Do you know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see where #vtagViewTwo so I don't know if it's correct.

Comment: That is the `id` of the form. Sorry. I updated my question

Comment: Look at my edit and try to run the code snippet. It should be working. Are you sure you have jQuery enabled?

Comment: jQuery is enabled. I tried your latest code, but it still not showing. In console window, it is trapping error `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` at the `$(".editButton").click(function(event){` line. I am putting the script after the form. That is the only difference now with your code. I guess it is not the problem

Comment: oh wait...my jQuery calling was somehow commented. Now the alert is working, but with `undefined`

Comment: Although your code is not working when I used in my dynamic table in the actual scenario, but your code is working when do it offline. So I am going to mark as answer. Probably something is going wrong when all comes together in my actual codes.